# Application or Icon on desktop which opens a website in default browser (Mac & Windows)

Tags: windows, macos, operating-system

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to create a desktop icon that when clicked will open a url in the user's default browser.

The solution should work for mac & windows (or alternatively will need a separate solution for windows and mac).

For this situation, creating a webpage shortcut from the browser is not enough. It needs to be an .exe or app.

I remember being able to do this with Flash back in the early 2000's.

Comment: `creating a webpage shortcut from the browser is not enough` Why?

Comment: The client does not want the little shortcut icon that appears over the desktop icon when it's a shortcut.